# Overlapping dates-Start Date should be the next day of the Enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with modifying my query.I observed that my query does not identify all the overlapping records, for instance in the above list of records it could identify the overlapping dates and as per my requirement the RowEffectiveDate should be the next day of RowEndDate, but it is kind off difficult for this particular record. It will just remove 2 records 8903 and 8904 from the table and will keep all other records. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
The query that i am using is mentioned below:

```
    CREATE TABLE #dimP (
  pcode char(4),
  pkey int,
  RowEffectiveDate datetime,
  rowenddate datetime
);
INSERT INTO #dimP (pcode, pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate)
  VALUES  
              ('PL56',8855,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2018-02-13 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8856,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-14 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8903,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-15 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8904,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-16 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8935,'2018-02-14 00:00:00.000','2018-02-17 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8944,'2018-02-15 00:00:00.000','2018-02-18 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8955,'2018-02-16 00:00:00.000','2018-03-02 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8965,'2018-02-17 00:00:00.000','2018-03-03 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8972,'2018-02-18 00:00:00.000','2018-03-04 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',8973,'2018-02-19 00:00:00.000','2018-03-05 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',9114,'2018-03-03 00:00:00.000','2018-04-24 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',9115,'2018-03-04 00:00:00.000','2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',9136,'2018-03-05 00:00:00.000','2018-04-26 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',9140,'2018-03-06 00:00:00.000','2018-04-29 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',11597,'2018-04-25 00:00:00.000','2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',11820,'2018-04-26 00:00:00.000','2018-04-26 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',11837,'2018-04-27 00:00:00.000','2018-04-29 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',11839,'2018-04-30 00:00:00.000','2018-05-22 23:59:59.997'),
              ('PL56',12372,'2018-05-23 00:00:00.000','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000');

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowEffectiveDate ORDER BY rowenddate, PKey) AS rn
FROM #dimP;

WITH CTE AS (

  SELECT pcode,pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowEffectiveDate ORDER BY rowenddate, PKey) AS rn
  FROM #dimP
  WHERE pcode='KO18'
)
SELECT rn, pcode, pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER  BY rn;

DROP TABLE #dimP;
```

Current output:

```
pcode  pkey          RowEffectiveDate         rowenddate
PL56    8855    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-02-13 23:59:59.997
PL56    8856    2018-02-09 15:09:52.000 2018-02-14 23:59:59.997
PL56    8903    2018-02-09 15:09:52.000 2018-02-15 23:59:59.997
PL56    8904    2018-02-09 15:09:52.000 2018-02-16 23:59:59.997
PL56    8935    2018-02-14 00:00:00.000 2018-02-17 23:59:59.997
PL56    8944    2018-02-15 00:00:00.000 2018-02-18 23:59:59.997
PL56    8955    2018-02-16 00:00:00.000 2018-03-02 23:59:59.997
PL56    8965    2018-02-17 00:00:00.000 2018-03-03 23:59:59.997
PL56    8972    2018-02-18 00:00:00.000 2018-03-04 23:59:59.997
PL56    8973    2018-02-19 00:00:00.000 2018-03-05 23:59:59.997
PL56    9114    2018-03-03 00:00:00.000 2018-04-24 23:59:59.997
PL56    9115    2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
PL56    9136    2018-03-05 00:00:00.000 2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
PL56    9140    2018-03-06 00:00:00.000 2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
PL56    11597   2018-04-25 00:00:00.000 2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
PL56    11820   2018-04-26 00:00:00.000 2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
PL56    11837   2018-04-27 00:00:00.000 2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
PL56    11839   2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-05-22 23:59:59.997
PL56    12372   2018-05-23 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Expected Output should be:

```
pcode   pkey    RowEffectiveDate           rowenddate
PL56    8855    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-02-13 23:59:59.997
PL56    8935    2018-02-14 00:00:00.000 2018-02-17 23:59:59.997
PL56    8972    2018-02-18 00:00:00.000 2018-03-04 23:59:59.997
PL56    9136    2018-03-05 00:00:00.000 2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
PL56    11837   2018-04-27 00:00:00.000 2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
PL56    11839   2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-05-22 23:59:59.997
PL56    12372   2018-05-23 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: It took me a bit to understand your requirement so I edited with a little bit of psuedo code, if that might make it easier for others.

Comment: This is a Gaps and Islands problem.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio :14.0.17254.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools         :14.0.1016.251
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) :10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML      :3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer    :9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework    :4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      :6.3.16299

Comment: Your first initial problem is the fact that you're doing `PARTITION BY RowEffectiveDate`.  Note that it's normally recommended to make end dates exclusive (`<`), which doesn't help if you already have an inclusive date, but would in the future.  Especially if you move to `datetime2`, which changes the resolution of the data.  What should happen to the overlapping-but-not included rows?  What if there's _two_ matching start times?

Comment: Is a stored procedure fair game? I have no doubt a vanilla SQL solution is possible, but a stored procedure could be more simple and intuitive.

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea to get rid of the partition by. The overlapping-but-not included rows should not be shown in the output and in case of two matching timings and dates, we should just make sure that the roweffectivedate is the following day of the rowenddate and just keep the records we need.

Comment: @Sanky On the SQL Server you're using, run `SELECT @@version`. That'll give you the version of the SQL Server that you're working with.

Comment: Okay. It's Sql server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually easier than I thought it was.

However, please note that I'm not convinced this is the "proper" solution (as opposed to *condensing* or combining the date ranges), and I have a sneaking suspicion the desired result set should actually be available in the raw.

It turns out that mostly all we need is a recursive query:

```
WITH R AS (SELECT pcode, pkey, rowEffectiveDate, rowEndDate
           FROM dimP AS a
           -- This makes it get the "first" row, with no other rows starting before it
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM dimP AS b
                             WHERE b.pcode = a.pcode
                                   AND b.rowEffectiveDate < a.rowEffectiveDate)
           UNION ALL
           SELECT curr.pcode, curr.pkey, curr.rowEffectiveDate, curr.rowEndDate
           FROM dimP AS curr
           JOIN R
             ON R.pcode = curr.pcode
                -- This date math is very fragile, and the data should be changed
                -- so that then end-value is exclusive, and equal to the next start
                AND DATEADD(ms, 3, R.rowEndDate) = curr.rowEffectiveDate)

SELECT *
FROM R
ORDER BY pcode, rowEffectiveDate
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bac2a/4/0)</kbd>
(Note this almost completely breaks if there's a duplicate "second" row)

Which yields the expected:

```
pcode   pkey    rowEffectiveDate        rowEndDate
----------------------------------------------------------------
PL56    8855    1900-01-01T00:00:00Z    2018-02-13T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    8935    2018-02-14T00:00:00Z    2018-02-17T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    8972    2018-02-18T00:00:00Z    2018-03-04T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    9136    2018-03-05T00:00:00Z    2018-04-26T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    11837   2018-04-27T00:00:00Z    2018-04-29T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    11839   2018-04-30T00:00:00Z    2018-05-22T23:59:59.997Z
PL56    12372   2018-05-23T00:00:00Z    9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, but this query does not give any output. It kept running for 2 hours without any result.

Comment: ...which most likely means that 1) your source set is reasonably large and 2) that you don't have any effective indices.  The fact that the query calls `DATEADD` is going to especially hurt there.  If the row-start value matched the row-end value, then an index on `(pcode, rowEndDate)` and `(pcode, rowEffectiveDate)` would help.  You might want to look at a computed index...

Comment: Yes, i have a large set of record. Also, there are indexes already present for the columns specified. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got an idea about how to tackle this situation and i got it using a recursive CTE.

```
Drop table if exists #dimP
go

CREATE TABLE #dimP (
  pcode char(4),
  pkey int,
  RowEffectiveDate datetime,
  rowenddate datetime
);
INSERT INTO #dimP (pcode, pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate)
  VALUES  
      ('PL56',8855,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2018-02-13 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8856,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-14 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8903,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-15 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8904,'2018-02-09 15:09:52.000','2018-02-16 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8935,'2018-02-14 00:00:00.000','2018-02-17 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8944,'2018-02-15 00:00:00.000','2018-02-18 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8955,'2018-02-16 00:00:00.000','2018-03-02 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8965,'2018-02-17 00:00:00.000','2018-03-03 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8972,'2018-02-18 00:00:00.000','2018-03-04 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',8973,'2018-02-19 00:00:00.000','2018-03-05 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',9114,'2018-03-03 00:00:00.000','2018-04-24 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',9115,'2018-03-04 00:00:00.000','2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',9136,'2018-03-05 00:00:00.000','2018-04-26 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',9140,'2018-03-06 00:00:00.000','2018-04-29 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',11597,'2018-04-25 00:00:00.000','2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',11820,'2018-04-26 00:00:00.000','2018-04-26 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',11837,'2018-04-27 00:00:00.000','2018-04-29 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',11839,'2018-04-30 00:00:00.000','2018-05-22 23:59:59.997'),
      ('PL56',12372,'2018-05-23 00:00:00.000','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #dimP (pcode, pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate)
  VALUES  ('KO18', 502  , '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-12-06 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 5431 , '2017-12-07 00:00:00.000', '2018-01-29 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 6852 , '2018-01-30 00:00:00.000', '2018-02-09 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 8861 , '2018-02-10 00:00:00.000', '2018-04-24 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 8862 , '2018-02-10 00:00:00.000', '2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 11764, '2018-04-25 00:00:00.000', '2018-04-25 23:59:59.997'),
    ('KO18', 11797, '2018-04-26 00:00:00.000', '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000');

/*
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowEffectiveDate ORDER BY rowenddate, PKey) AS rn
FROM #dimP
order by 1, 2
*/

;WITH CTE AS (
select pcode,pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate,RowEffectiveDateCalc,RowEndDateCalc
  from (
          SELECT pcode,pkey, RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate
                    ,cast(RowEffectiveDate as date)  RowEffectiveDateCalc
                    ,cast(rowenddate as date)  RowEndDateCalc
                    ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pcode ORDER BY RowEffectiveDate, rowenddate, PKey) AS rn
          FROM #dimP
--          where PCode = 'PL56'
        ) X
    where rn = 1
union all
    SELECT NextRow.PCode, NextRow.Pkey, NextRow.RowEffectiveDate, NextRow.rowenddate
            ,cast(NextRow.RowEffectiveDate as date)  RowEffectiveDateCalc
                    ,cast(NextRow.rowenddate as date)  RowEndDateCalc
    FROM CTE CurRow
        join #dimP NextRow
        on CurRow.PCode = NextRow.PCode
        and DateDiff(day, CurRow.RowEndDateCalc, cast(NextRow.RowEffectiveDate as date)) = 1
)

select * from CTE
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: ... naively, this feels like it should be significantly _slower_ than my proposed solution.  Any chance you can post the execution plans?

Comment: It looked like it would work faster for all my records. but that one just worked faster  for 1 record. I am back to 0 with my new query and this one too is taking loner time to run with no success.